# Printing part of object's string

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

Let's say I have a class like this:

```py
class Cls:
    def __init__(self, a,b,c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.a} {self.b} {self.c}"
```

and I want to print only the first two items. I can do this by brute force:

```py
c = Cls(1,2,3)
print(str(c)[:3])
```

But, is there a more elegant (Pythonic) way to do this?

Comment: `print(f"{c.a} {c.b}")` would be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Your slice only works if the first 2 items are only 1 digit each.

You should split the string into a list using whitespace delimiters and slice that.

```
c = Cls(12, 345, 6)
print(*str(c).split()[:2])
```

Comment: This is actually a very interesting software engineering question: how much of the internal implementation should we rely on?  Your solution does solve the problem, but it assumes the implementation of `__str__`, which might change.  My suggestion relies on the member variables, but if those are the pieces of data we want, I'd argue that's a better way to do it.

Comment: He said "part of an object's string", which suggests that the string format is something we can rely on.